# Law of supremum of time-scaled Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I would like to know if there is a formula for the law of 
$$
\sup_{l \leq t \leq u} \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}}
$$
where $B$ is a standard Brownian motion, and $0 < l < u < 1$ are constants?

The law of $\sup_{l \leq t \leq u} B_t$ itself is well-known, but I couldn't find in any textbook at hand the law of the quantity that I am interested in..

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I think there is a problem at $0$. Brownian motion is not Holder continuous with exponent $1/2$.

Comment: So the $\sup$ should be infinite.

Comment: @Michael, you are right. I carelessly put 0 and 1, which is not really the case in my work.